# Set image border with XUL

Tags: firefox-addon, border, xul

How can I set a border to an image with XUL?

I've tried with

```
var img = document.createElement("image");
img.setAttribute("id","users_1");
img.setAttribute("style","width:30px;height:30px;cursor:pointer;border:1px solid");
```

But it seems to ignore it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify a color in your border defintion:

change `border:1px solid` to `border:1px solid black`

borders definitely work in xul